# Rewriting URL rules

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am accepting a URL such as the following:

```
http://www.random.com/film/1
```

What I need to do with this is send it to `server.php` in the base directory and then explode the address on `/` and use the film and 1 as variables.

How do I achieve this?

At the moment, that link says no page exists!!

Comment: Nothing to do with PHP; depends on your server. If you use Apache, look at `.htaccess` files. Similar questions have been asked a lot in the past on this site.

Comment: Ok it's to do with the server but I've got no idea where to even start!

Comment: That duplicate you mention doesn't explain it how I would like. When I enter the above URL, how do I resolve it by going to server.php and then have the film and 1 available to use? I only ever need 2 paramaters. That other question only uses 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because I already have it open, create a `.htaccess` file like the following for apache:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?(.*)$ server.php?1=$1&2=$2&3=$3&4=$4 [NC,QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Severely modified from my first answer based on the comments, so to summarize what's here now with what will be in PHP:
`/api-v1/v1/film/1` will give you the following `$_GET`:

```
Array
(
    [1] => api-v1
    [2] => v1
    [3] => film
    [4] => 1
)
```

The fourth parameter, in this case `1` is optional, omitting it and using `/api-v1/v1/film` or `/api-v1/v1/film/` would give you:

```
Array
(
    [1] => api-v1
    [2] => v1
    [3] => film
    [4] => 
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one more thing, what if I don't have a second parameter. The second part is optional!

Comment: Just made an edit, with the edit though, the `opt` will contain the slash, so you can remove it with `substr($_GET['opt'], 1)` in PHP ^^

Comment: I'm extremely sorry but I need three parameters and that's final. I need the first 2 always be set and the 3rd one to be optional. Could you alter the solution for me one last time!

Comment: Works perfectly except it gives me the following error, The requested URL /api-v1/v1/film/ was not found on this server, if the number isn't on the end. If you add a 1 onto the end, it works but I need it to work without the number on the end!

Comment: `1` on the end where? after `film`? or after the `v1`? (Please show the example that did work as well =] )

Comment: Sorry! I'll put the full url here! http://localhost:8888/api-v1/v1/film/1 - that works. http://localhost:8888/api-v1/v1/film - this doesn't work! I need both to work!

Comment: Ok, made an edit if you need `localhost:8888/api-v1/v1/film/1` to work, that is 4 fields to capture - do you need all 4? With the edit `/film/1` and `/film` would both be put in `$_GET['maybe']`

Comment: Suppose I do need the extra field to keep the directory tidy. So I need all 4? Can you make them all seperate? I've just changed the htaccess to 1=$1 2=$2 etc.

Comment: Ok, made another edit and updated the description to match the change you said you made.  If we need to make any more changes, please click the link to move this to chat so we don't bloat these comments while making it work =]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28218/discussion-between-luke-and-jon)

Comment: The most helpful user I've ever come across on here! He answered the answer, changed it, answered it again and then answered again! Awesome! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You should be looking at `.htaccess` files for this kind of redirection, and not quite a duplication of the other listings:

In `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ server.php?$1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ server.php?$1 [L]
```

In `server.php`:

```
$parameterName = 'film';
$parameterValue = isset($_GET[$parameterName]) ? $_GET[$parameterName] : NULL;

if (!is_null($parameterValue)) {
    echo "Parameter found";
} else {
    echo "Parameter not found";
}
```

Comment: Should be noted with this version that `file` won't be readily available, but rather `$_GET['file'] = 1` in this case, so if you change `file` in the URL to 'stuff', PHP would need `$_GET['stuff']` in order to get the `1`. ^^

Comment: True. In fact, now that the "value" is optional, your solution @Jon is most likely going to be a better fit.

Comment: My one now just will redirect to `server.php?film=1` or `server.php?film`, so you can easily test for no value in PHP.

Comment: Hrm, personally, I would modify the second rule to `variable=value` type rather than just setting a variable like that. =]

Comment: Easily changed. Your solution is still going to work better in this case regardless... much more scalable.